# why large file is corrupting sometimes while uploading it to Azure blob

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am uploading a large file in azure storage . I am uploading a file in to 4 MB chunks. I used the following code from last 1 year but from last one month whenever I am uploading file It is getting corrupt some times and some times It uploads fine.

Can any one suggest me what I need to change in the code.

//Uploads a file from the file system to a blob. Parallel implementation.

```
public void ParallelUploadFile(CloudBlockBlob blob1, string fileName1, BlobRequestOptions options1, int maxBlockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024, int rowId)
        {
            blob = blob1;
            fileName = fileName1;
            options = options1;

            file = new FileInfo(fileName);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);
            long fileSize = file.Length;
        //Get the filesize
        long fileSizeInMb = file.Length/1024/1024;

        // let's figure out how big the file is here
        long leftToRead = fileSize;
        long startPosition = 0;

        // have 1 block for every maxBlockSize bytes plus 1 for the remainder
        var blockCount =
            ((int) Math.Floor((double) (fileSize/maxBlockSize))) + 1;

        blockIds = new List<string>();

        // populate the control array...
        for (int j = 0; j < blockCount; j++)
        {
            var toRead = (int) (maxBlockSize < leftToRead
                                    ? maxBlockSize
                                    : leftToRead);

            var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String( 
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("BlockId{0}", j.ToString("0000000"))));


            transferDetails.Add(new BlockTransferDetail()
                                    {
                                        StartPosition = startPosition,
                                        BytesToRead = toRead,
                                        BlockId = blockId
                                    });

            if (toRead > 0)
            {
                blockIds.Add(blockId);
            }

            // increment the starting position
            startPosition += toRead;
            leftToRead -= toRead;
        }

        //*******
        //PUT THE NO OF THREAD LOGIC HERE
        //*******

        int runFrom = 0;
        int runTo = 0;
        int uploadParametersCount = 0;
        TotalUpload = Convert.ToInt64(fileSizeInMb);

        for (int count = 0; count < transferDetails.Count; )
        {
            //Create uploading file parameters
            uploadParametersesList.Add(new UploadParameters()
                                           {
                                               FileName = file.FullName,
                                               BlockSize = 3900000,
                                               //BlockSize = 4194304,
                                               LoopFrom = runFrom + runTo,
                                               IsPutBlockList = false,
                                               UploadedBytes = 0,
                                               Fs = fileStream,
                                               RowIndex = rowId,
                                               FileSize = Convert.ToInt64(fileSizeInMb)
                                           });


            //Logic to create correct threads
            if (transferDetails.Count < 50)
            {
                runTo = transferDetails.Count;
                uploadParametersesList[uploadParametersCount].LoopTo += runTo;
                count += transferDetails.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                var tmp = transferDetails.Count - runTo;
                if (tmp > 50 && tmp < 100)
                {
                    runTo += tmp;
                    count += tmp;
                    uploadParametersesList[uploadParametersCount].LoopTo += runTo;
                }
                else
                {
                    runTo += 50;
                    count += 50;
                    uploadParametersesList[uploadParametersCount].LoopTo += runTo;
                }
            }

            //Add to Global Const
            GlobalConst.UploadedParameters.Add(uploadParametersesList[uploadParametersCount]);

            //Start the thread
            int parametersCount = uploadParametersCount;
            var thread = new Thread(() => ThRunThis(uploadParametersesList[parametersCount]))
                             {Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest};
            thread.Start();

            uploadParametersCount++;

            //Start a timer here to put all blocks on azure blob
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Interval = 5000;
            aTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    //Timer callback
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (uploadParametersesList.Count(o => o.IsPutBlockList) == uploadParametersesList.Count)
        {
            aTimer.Elapsed -= OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Stop();

            //Finally commit it
            try
            {
                uploadParametersesList.ForEach(x => x.Status = "Uploaded");
                blob.PutBlockList(blockIds);

                IsCompleted = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    //Main thread
    private void ThRunThis(UploadParameters uploadParameters)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int j = uploadParameters.LoopFrom; j < uploadParameters.LoopTo; j++)
            {
                br = new BinaryReader(uploadParameters.Fs);
                var bytes = new byte[transferDetails[j].BytesToRead];

                //move the file system reader to the proper position
                uploadParameters.Fs.Seek(transferDetails[j].StartPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                br.Read(bytes, 0, transferDetails[j].BytesToRead);

                if (bytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    //calculate the block-level hash
                    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                    byte[] blockHash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
                    string convertedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(blockHash, 0, 16);
                    blob.PutBlock(transferDetails[j].BlockId, new MemoryStream(bytes), convertedHash, options);

                    //Update Uploaded Bytes
                    uploadParameters.UploadedBytes += transferDetails[j].BytesToRead;
                    TotalUploadedBytes += transferDetails[j].BytesToRead;
                    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                    //Try to free the memory
                    try
                    {
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Is Completed
            uploadParameters.IsPutBlockList = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            uploadParameters.Exception = exception.Message;
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I touched large blob upload with threads, but it looks like your block list is getting out of sequence by threads.

Why don't you get the block list from cloud once all blocks have been uploaded and then use that list for putBlockList. That would make sure you get them in correct sequence.